# scalafmt configuration similar to IntelliJ ones

Tags: scalafmt

Is there a scalafmt config which is reformat code the same way like IntelliJ with scala plugin does now ?
I have a problem with configuring it, and my team mates use IntelliJ only I VsCode and very often I need just open IntelliJ to reformat code :)

thanks